# Can't get focusout to work like I want

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-focusout

I'm having more problem with jquery selector... I'm inserting user form sith POST ajax, and I might have more than one form with the same class at once.

I've manage to grab the last form inserted with this line :

```
var NewForm = $(".myform").last();
```

and it does the job ok as I cant use :

```
$(NewForm).css()...
```

To set the curent form display. Now I'm trying to have some "focusout" event to trigger. When I place the following code, the focusout event work, but for all ".myform" class.

```
$('.myform input[name="test"]').focusout(function() {
   Alert('This Work');
});
```

I would need only the last form to have the focusout event attach. I've tried the following :

```
$(NewForm).children('input[name="test"]').focusout() {
   Alert('this is not working');
});
```

without success, I've also replace "children".

the HTML is similar to this :

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="myform">
      <form class="formtype">
          <input name="test">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('input[name="test"]', NewForm).focusout() {
   Alert('this is not working');
});
```

That is, using the context parameter so you search for your selector only inside the `NewForm` element.